# How can I programmatically get the Bluetooth address of an iPhone Device in iOS7

Tags: bluetooth, ios7

I want to determine the BLUETOOTH ADDRESS for an iPhone or iPad from within an app on said device. But I didn't find any API that will return the BLUETOOTH ADDRESS or name of a device. 
In [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW34) it is written that "In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device, the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00", but there is no documentation regarding BLUETOOTH ADDRESS.

Please help me for finding the BLUETOOTH ADDRESS in iOS7.

Comment: What are you defining as a BT address? What do you need it for?

Comment: BT MAC Address. I just want to make an app that shows device BT MAC Address and BT name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the Bluetooth Address in iOS 7.